# C++ - compilation fails on calling overloaded function in std::thread

Tags: c++

Consider the following scenario:

**// utils.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

namespace Utils {
    void do_something(int a, std::list<int> *b);
    void do_something(int a, std::list<std::string> *b);
};
```

**// utils.cpp**

```
#include "utils.h"

void Utils::do_something(int a, std::list<int> *b) {

}

void Utils::do_something(int a, std::list<std::string> *b) {

}
```

**// main.cpp**

```
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include "utils.h"

int main() {
    std::list<int> list;
    std::thread t(Utils::do_something, 17, &list);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, std::list<int>*)'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Before I added the overloading function that gets `std::list<std::string>*`, it did compile well.

Comment: Are the two `Utils::do_something` functions doing (roughly) the same thing? If not, then using different (and more descriptive) function names will solve it.

Comment: This is an obvious solution that I totally agree with you about. But is it a documented problem that threads can't take overloaded functions?

Comment: I suspect it's a bit of a stretch to expect that the compiler can deduce the correct overload for the first parameter based solely on the types of the remaining parameters but hopefully someone will be able to quote from the standard why this can't (or can) be done. Interesting question.

Comment: @SomethingSomething it's wider than that: everything that takes a generic functor will choke on a complete overload set (or a function template). `std::thread`, the `<algorithm>` functions, etc.

Comment: Qt has a related function [qOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) for that that is not Qt-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is even though you pass the parameters to `std::thread` it does not use those to try and determine the function passed to it.  It tries to resolve the function type in isolation.  When it does so, it sees there are two different versions and so it stops, as it does not know which one you want.

Unfortunately You are going to have to tell the compiler which function you want to use.  You can do that by casting the function to the specific function pointer you want.

Instead of doing that though you can use a lambda to make this easy by allowing overload resolution to take place in a regular function call like

```
std::thread t([](auto first, auto second){ return Utils::do_something(first, second); }, 17, &list);
```

This will also work well with member functions as you just capture the object to call the function on with the capture list of the lambda.  That saves you from having to pass that object to `std::thread` or using `std::bind`.

Comment: Well, we didn't really tell which function to use there -- rather, this delays automatic overload resolution so it can use the provided parameters :)

Comment: @Quentin Updated the language.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `static_cast` to disambiguate the overloads...

```
std::thread t(static_cast<void(*)(int, std::list<int> *)>(&Utils::do_something), 17, &list);
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, if I need to specify manually the signature, I will prefer to use the "obvious solution" of naming the functions differently. The question is whether there's anything else to do