# overloading global function with unique_ptr and raw pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, unique-ptr, stdthread

I've been developing a feature in c++, that is using some legacy code written C language.

I've been facing compiler error with overloaded versions of a function that either takes `unique_ptr` or a raw pointer of the same type.

Simplified version of my code is given below:

```
class A{
public:
    A():mDummy(0) { }
    ~A()=default;
    int mDummy;
};

void handleObj(std::unique_ptr<A> ap){
    std::cout<<ap->mDummy<<'\n';
}

void handleObj(A* ap){
    std::cout<<ap->mDummy<<'\n';
}

int main(){

    std::unique_ptr<A> obj{new A()};
    std::thread t1{handleObj, std::move(obj)};

    A* obj2{ new A()};
    std::thread t2{handleObj, obj2};

    if(t1.joinable())
        t1.join();

    if(t2.joinable())
        t2.join();
}
```

when compiled getting this error:

```
/Users/overload_uniquePtr_rawPtr/main.cpp:29:17: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
    std::thread t1{handleObj, std::move(obj)};
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:359:9: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Fp'
thread::thread(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:289:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:315:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__t', but 2 arguments were provided
    thread(thread&& __t) _NOEXCEPT : __t_(__t.__t_) {__t.__t_ = _LIBCPP_NULL_THREAD;}
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:296:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(_LIBCPP_NULL_THREAD) {}
```

Can some body help me understand whats wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - compilation fails on calling overloaded function in std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049407/c-compilation-fails-on-calling-overloaded-function-in-stdthread)

Comment: This is a similar problem, answer helps me. Thank you @arnes

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand the compiler cant deduce which of the functions you want to construct std::thread with. There's a proposal for a `std::overload` which I believe would help you out but right now you can do something like this:

```cpp
std::thread t1([](auto&& x) { handleObj(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)); }, std::move(obj));
```

Comment: Thank you @MaLarsson.  Your solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the template reduction failure . The thread object's construct function is a template,it will fail when the argument function is overloaded. You can solve it like this:

`std::thread t1{static_cast<void (*)(std::unique_ptr<A>)>(handleObj),obj};`